# ggplot inside for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I want to run through six similar dataframes and print out six plots using ggplot.

My code works when I run the plots separately but I can't get ggplot to run six times using a for loop. My six dataframes are the six animals listed in gg_pets.

```
cat <- data.frame(Breed = c("American Shorthair","Ragdoll","Persian","Sphynx","Maine Coon"), 
Longevity = c("17","19","15","17","20"))

dog <- data.frame(Breed = c("Havanese","Bulldog","Beagle","Chihuahua","Poodle"), 
Longevity = c("20","11","12","15","16"))

#etc for types of birds, fish, snakes, and ferrets

#the following works
plot <- ggplot(data = cat, aes(x = Breed, y = Longevity, fill = Breed)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  xlab("Breed") +
  ylab("Longevity") +
  ggtitle("cat") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Longevity), vjust = -0.3, color = "black", size = 3.5) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black"), axis.text = element_text(color = "black"), 
        legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 0.8),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA), text = element_text(size=10))
print(plot)

gg_pets <- c("cat","dog","bird","fish","snake","ferret")

#the following does not work
for (i in 1:length(gg_pets)){
    plot <- ggplot(data = [i], aes(x = Breed, y = Longevity, fill = Breed)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
    xlab("Breed") +
    ylab("Longevity") +
    ggtitle([i]) +
    geom_text(aes(label = Longevity), vjust = -0.3, color = "black", size = 3.5) +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black"), axis.text = element_text(color = "black"), 
          legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 0.8),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA), text = element_text(size=10))
    print(plot)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example gg_pets is just a vector of strings. You need to concatenate the data frames in order to iterated over them in the for-loop. You can do it with a list. As follows. You can use the names of the items as a title.

```
...
gg_pets <- list(cat=cat, dog=dog)

#the following does not work
for (i in 1:length(gg_pets)) {
  plot <- ggplot(data = gg_pets[[i]], aes(x = Breed, y = Longevity, fill = Breed)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
    xlab("Breed") +
    ylab("Longevity") +
    ggtitle(names(gg_pets)[i]) +
    geom_text(aes(label = Longevity), vjust = -0.3, color = "black", size = 3.5) +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black"), axis.text = element_text(color = "black"), 
          legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 0.8),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA), text = element_text(size=10))
  print(plot)
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. How can I plot all six figures in the same window? Adding ```par(mfrow = c(2,3))``` before the for loop and just inside the for loop doesn't work.

Comment: @Bex save the plots of the for-loop in a list too. `
plots <- list()
for (i in 1:length(gg_pets)) {
  plots[[i]] <- ggplot(data = gg_pets[[i]], ...`
Then use `grid.arrange` from gridExtra package to put them together as you wish. Here is an example: `gridExtra::grid.arrange(plots[[1]], plots[[2]], plots[[1]], plots[[2]], layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,2),c(3,4)))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
ggplot(data = get(i), ...)
```

but it would probably be more idiomatic/better practice to put your data sets in a named list (`my_data_list <- list(cat=cat, dog=dog, ...)` or even `my_data_list <- mget(gg_pets)` ) and use `data = my_data_list[[i]]` ...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the `list` approach mentioned in the other answers would be to first have everything in the same `data.frame`, since apparently all the tables have the same variables; and then have one more variable indicating what kind of pet does the observation correspond to. As follows:

```
pets_df <- bind_rows(cat %>% add_column(pet = 'cat'),
                     dog %>% add_column(pet = 'dog'))

> pets_df
                Breed Longevity pet
1  American Shorthair        17 cat
2             Ragdoll        19 cat
3             Persian        15 cat
4              Sphynx        17 cat
5          Maine Coon        20 cat
6            Havanese        20 dog
7             Bulldog        11 dog
8              Beagle        12 dog
9           Chihuahua        15 dog
10             Poodle        16 dog
```

Then, in each iteration of the loop you only have to filter the one `data.frame`. For example:

```
for (i in 1:length(gg_pets)) {
  plot <- ggplot(data = filter(pets_df, pet == gg_pets[i]), 
                 aes(x = Breed, y = Longevity, fill = Breed)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
    xlab("Breed") +
    ylab("Longevity") +
    ggtitle(gg_pets[i]) +
    geom_text(aes(label = Longevity), vjust = -0.3, color = "black", size = 3.5) +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black"), axis.text = element_text(color = "black"), 
          legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 0.8),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA), text = element_text(size=10))
  print(plot)
}
```